# Using recordset without a db to connect to; runtime error 3709

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

The aim here is to copy a few rows of Excel data into a recordset object, using a header row for field names, without any sort of database/database connection in the picture. (It has been claimed, by Microsoft themselves, that this is possible: ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa260348(v=vs.60) ).)

When I run the below code, the rs.Open line gets me this: "Run-time error '3709':
The connection cannot be used to perform this operation.  It is either closed or invalid in this context."  How is it that "Open"ing a new recordset object cannot be used due to the object being... er, closed?  In what other way is it "invalid in this context?"

EDIT: In respone to Tim's comment below, I have tried to define fields in the recordset using the .Append statements now added. Now I get a runtime error 3001; "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."  I'm flummoxed considering this page from Microsoft lays out the .Append method's requirements....

```
Sub create_rs()

'Create the recordset object
Set rs = New Recordset

rs.Fields.Append "Locator", adChar
rs.Fields.Append "Carrier", adChar
rs.Fields.Append "Destin", adChar
rs.Fields.Append "Depart", adDate
rs.Fields.Append "Returndate", adDate


'Get the fieldnames from row #1
'and prepare fieldstring for use in rs.AddNew

For fieldcount = 1 To 5
    fieldname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, fieldcount)
    
    If fieldcount <> 5 Then
    fieldstring = fieldstring & fieldname & ", "
    Else
    fieldstring = fieldstring & fieldname
    End If

Next fieldcount

'Get the data from rows 2 thru 8
'and prepare valuestring for use in rs.AddNew
For allrows = 2 To 8

    valuestring = ""

    For valuecount = 1 To 5
    valuename = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(allrows, valuecount)
    
    If valuecount <> 5 Then
        valuestring = valuestring & valuename & ", "
    Else
        valuestring = valuestring & valuename
    End If
    
    rs.AddNew fieldstring, valuestring
    
    Next valuecount

Next allrows

rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your recordset has no fields.  You need to add those first - eg see https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.data.ado/c/xn6hVWvwwLw?pli=1

Comment: You don't need any of those lines as their is no database. Just use the recordset. So delete lines 6,7,8, and 10.

Comment: "Now I get a runtime error" - where exactly do you get that?

Comment: You're passing two comma-delimited list of items to `AddNew`, but it expects either two single values or two arrays...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/addnew-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=Optional.%20A%20single%20name%2C%20or%20an%20array%20of%20names%20or%20ordinal%20positions%20of%20the%20fields%20in%20the%20new%20record.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Sub create_rs()

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset, allrows As Long, rngData As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range, col As Long
    
    'Create the recordset object
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Fields.Append "Locator", adChar, 30 '<< adChar needs a size...
    rs.Fields.Append "Carrier", adChar, 30
    rs.Fields.Append "Destin", adChar, 30
    rs.Fields.Append "Depart", adDate
    rs.Fields.Append "Returndate", adDate
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    rs.Open
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A2:E8").Rows
        rs.AddNew         'add a new record
        For col = 1 To 5  'fill the record
            rs.Fields(col - 1).Value = rw.Cells(col).Value
        Next col
    Next rw

    rs.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
    'dump the content
    Debug.Print rs.GetString(adClipString, -1, vbLf, vbLf & vbLf, "<null>")

End Sub
```